# Pulling files from server in PHP to edit

Tags: php, file, resize

I'm trying to resize a bunch of photos that have been previously uploaded via a web interface. The files are off the webroot like

/_uploads/filename.jpg

I search my DB and get all the urls for the photos then send them to my photo resizing class. I'm geting the following error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in (path to source)

I've tried both of these but neither work. This is on Window too if that helps...

Also the class works when resizing on upload.

```
// option 1
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 
    $curfile = "/_uploads/".$row['filename'];
    $image->load($curImage);
    // other stuff...
}

// option 2
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 
    $curfile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/_uploads/".$row['filename'];
    $image->load($curImage);
    // other stuff...
}
```

Comment: shouldnt $curImage be $curfile? or was that a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all (as Adithya is saying), replace `$curImage` by `$curfile`.
Besides that, you don't seem to initialize `$image` (that's what the error is saying).
I don't know how your class is called, but say it's called `Image`, then you should add this above `$image->load ...`:

```
$image = new Image();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `$image` is not an object. That's what you need to fix - the code you posted is pretty much unrelated to it since it doesn't initialize `$image`.